# Typescript how to escape backslash character

Tags: typescript

I would like to create a regular expression in Typescript to match the decimal separator character followed by a sequence of `0`s in a string.  For example, if the decimal separator is `.`, then the expression I've come up with is:

```
/\.0+\b/g
```

Since the decimal separator is determined at run-time based on locale, I am constructing my expression in code, with the `decimalSeperator` as a variable:

```
 "/\\" + decimalSeperator + "0+\b/";
```

My intention is that the double backslash characters will be escaped to a single backslash character.

However, the double backslash characters are not being escaped in my compiled JavaScript:

```
"/\\" + decimalSeperator + "0+\b/"
```

Yet if I used a single backslash, the code won't compile due to the `"` being escaped:

```
"/\" + decimalSeperator + "0+\b/";
```

> - error TS1005: ',' expected.
> - error TS1127: Invalid character.
> - error TS1002: Unterminated string literal.

Is this a bug with Typescript or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? TypeScript is going to emit the JavaScript the same as it saw it. `"/\\"` is the JavaScript representation of forwardslash backslash, just as you intend.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> However, the double backslash characters are not being escaped in my compiled JavaScript

That is by intention. The *compile time JavaScript* will be very similar to pre compile TypeScript. `"\\"` will compile to `"\\"` . However at *runtime* `"\\"` will be `\` i.e. a single back slash.

```
console.log("\\"); // prints "\"
```

Comment: Ahh yes that makes sense.  Thanks